# Forecast the number of requests per second

Tags: stress-testing

I know the number of users who will use my web application. Do some special techniques exist to predict the rough number of requests per second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of requests will depend on how often a user uses the app and what exactly they do with it when they have the app opened. Since a user's behavior is unpredictable and can change on a daily basis, it is near impossible to predict the number of requests you can expect.

There may be days where they don't use the app *at all*, there may be days where they use it 20 times, there may be times when the user only is going to check something quickly, perhaps only making a single request, maybe the user is going to use the app extensively, making many requests. It all depends on factors you cannot control.

The people at the weather station spot trends and patterns in the weather, which they use to try to predict the upcoming weather. This is an approach you could take. Monitor your system's usage for a while and predict future usage based on the average usage so far, or something similar.

The longer you monitor, the more accurate it **can** get (no guarantees), but it will never be perfect.